# Hot wire not hot after moving?

Tags: wiring

Removed staple in rafters from my hot wire to move it over about foot and half to new location. Moved line over and turned breaker back on and now it's not hot anymore?  Did nothing but remove staple and move around board.

Comment: are you certain that you turned on the correct breaker?

Comment: Is this a wire or a cable (2-4 wires in one sheath)? Do you have a non contact voltage tester? Multimeter?

Answer (score 2):

Either pulled apart/loosen a connection, maybe at a junction box, or the wire is broken inside of the cable.

Turn off the breaker, since might have a loose hot wire, and check the circuit from end to end.